# page break if data row has a specific value in a returned table in SSRS 2008

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have dataset in SSRS report returning a table containing the data from single table grouped by a x looks like.

table procedure details has three columns **pagebreak** , **procName** , **Tasks** with values as shown below

```
0        p1        p1t2   
1        p2        p2t1  
0        p2        p2t2  
0        p2        p2t3
```

I want a page break at 1. any idea on how to do this.

Thanks,

Comment: Do you want to display tasks for each procName on different page (at first page p1, at second p2 and so on)?

Comment: If you could group by procName you just had to go to group setting and select "break each instance of a group".